# Convert DateTime from one TimeZone to another TimeZone - Swift

Tags: swift, datetime, timezone

I need to convert one `TimeZone` to another `TimeZone` for user and I am using from bellow code:

```
 let myTime = "2019-11-02 02:00:00"
 let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
 let date = dateFormatter.date(from: myTime)
 let source_timezone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: TimeZone.current.abbreviation()!)
 let local_timezone = NSTimeZone.system
 let source_EDT_offset = source_timezone?.secondsFromGMT(for: date!)
 let destination_EDT_offset = local_timezone.secondsFromGMT(for: date!)
 let time_interval : TimeInterval = Double(destination_EDT_offset - source_EDT_offset!)
 let final_date = NSDate(timeInterval: time_interval, since: date!)
print(final_date)
```

But get me `crash nil` here `(source_EDT_offset)`.

Comment: Your code runs fine for me in a playground but there are many issues anyway with forced unwrapping, no error handling for optionals, use of NS... classes instead of using Swift classes

Comment: Note that a `Date` does not store time zone information. You can't say "this `Date` is in `Europe/London` whereas this other one is in `America/New_York`". `Date`s represent _points in time_, or _instants_.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Which timezone is your date string? UTC/GMT server time or local time? Which timezone do you need to display to the user?

Comment: Why do you repeatedly force-unwrap variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is cleaned up version of your code with an example of how to run it, note that I select the "from" time zone that `myTime` has in this example

```
func changeToSystemTimeZone(_ date: Date, from: TimeZone, to: TimeZone = TimeZone.current) -> Date {
    let sourceOffset = from.secondsFromGMT(for: date)
    let destinationOffset = to.secondsFromGMT(for: date)
    let timeInterval = TimeInterval(destinationOffset - sourceOffset)
    return Date(timeInterval: timeInterval, since: date)
}
```

Example, note that you need to set a locale that matches the time zone for your input date (`myTime`)

```
let myTime = "2019-11-02 02:00:00"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: myTime), let timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC") {
    let offsetedDate = changeToSystemTimeZone(date, from: timeZone)
    print(date, Calendar.current.timeZone)
    print(offsetedDate, timeZone)
}
```

> 2019-11-02 01:00:00 +0000 Europe/Stockholm (current)
>   2019-11-02 02:00:00 +0000 GMT (fixed)

*Update: Added a parameter for time zone to convert to*

Comment: This will not work as expected for some locations depending on the device locale and settings. You should always set your date formatter locale to "en_US_POSIX" when parsing fixed date formats.

Comment: Btw there is a calendar method called `Calendar.current.dateComponents(in: TimeZone, from: Date)` or change the date formatter timezone if you just need to display the date to the user

Comment: @ Joakim Danielson. Not work. I tested with this site http://www.timezoneconverter.com/cgi-bin/tzc.tzc.

Comment: I tested from Asia/Tehran to US/Alaska, but not work.

Comment: @ Joakim Danielson. Above website show me:  02:00:00 Saturday November 2, 2019 in Asia/Tehran converts to
14:30:00 Friday November 1, 2019 in US/Alaska

Comment: @jojo Maybe you can use the code and experiment some yourself. For instance what does your input time represent and how do you need to set locale etc for the formatter. Anyway the main point of this answer was to write to code in a better maner so it wasn't so prone to crashing.